# Onde posso usar o -webkit-details-marker?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tava querendo remover a seta padrão da tag `details/summary` em HTML e achei essa solução de usar o `-webkit-details-marker`.
Queria saber o que ela realmente faz, pois não achei nenhum tutorial explicativo na net, apenas achei dizendo para colocar esse pseudo-elemento e iria funcionar. Funcionou, mas gostaria de mais informações sobre ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a  [Especificação WHATWG HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element):

> The details element represents a disclosure widget from which the user
>   can obtain additional information or controls.

O elemento `details` destina-se a criar um widget que tem por finalidade fornecer ao usuário informações adicionais sobre um conteúdo ou revelar um controle de formulário.
Nesse contexto, dois elementos são relevantes, o `<details>`, que é o container para todo o conteúdo a mostrar/esconder e o `<summary>`, que contém o sumário e o título da seção, sendo que ele é opcional, pois se não for utilizado, o navegador se encarregara de renderizar um texto padrão para o elemento.

Com o `<details>` você pode alterar a visibilidade dos comentários em um blog, perfis de usuários, detalhes de download, formulários complexos ou em aplicações web como mostrado no exemplo a seguir, constante das especificações:

Para estilizar o widget em `enginesWebKit` você pode usar a pseudo classe CSS `::-webkit-details-marker`.

```
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 500%;
}
```

Para você entender melhor, leia o artigo completo [aqui](http://www.maujor.com/blog/2011/08/10/elementos-details-e-summary-da-html5/).